# What is the cabal equivalent of `stack ghci app:exe:executable`?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I've previously used `stack ghci app:exe:executable` to get a list of any errors in my Haskell project managed via cabal.

However now that I'm not using stack, how would I achieve the above (essentially load all the modules from the executable defined in the cabal project file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix-local-build.html#cabal-v2-repl

```
cabal v2-repl executableNameGoesHere
```

Comment: btw, in case the executable's name is not unique in the current build-plan, you can qualify it by prefixing it by `exe:` or even `<pkgname>:exe:`